# jquery image effects

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use jquery effects to transfer an image to a div

this is the jquery code i'm using.

```
$('#btn-1').click(function() {
    $('#transferEffect').remove(); // Remove any existing one
    $('<style id="transferEffect" type="text/css">' + // Add new one
        '.ui-effects-transfer { background-image: url(' + $(this).attr('src') + '); }' +
        '</style>').appendTo('head');
    $(this).effect('transfer', {to: $('.target')}, 1000);
});
```

works great, but now that i'm trying to integrate it with my code, i can't seem to figure out how to get the id/name/class of the main image in div.

```
<div class="listing-result-row-holder" >
    <div class="listing-image">
        <a href="google.com"><img src="https://m1-s.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_60_60/p/3/000/02e/02d/35f521f.png" title="lego" id="img-1" class="img-polaroid" /></a>
        <div class="listing-total-image">1</div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="listing-detail">
        <div class="listing-result-title">
            <span class="listing-badge">bla bla</span>
            <span class="title_browse_ad"><a href="google.com">TITLE</a></span>
        </div>
        <span class="listing-detail-left">
            <div class="listing-more-info">
                <div class="row">RANDOM TEXT</div>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span class="listing-detail-right"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="pull-right" style="margin: 0 5px 5px 0;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn-1" name="saveLinkId-1" class="btn btn-link"><span> save</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="target"></div>
```

basically i would like the image effect to start when a user clicks on the "save" button. This is a dynamically generated page, so the ID's would change (example ID #btn-1 could be btn-2)

[here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/MhQpH/9/)

Comment: are you sure the above code is working .. since `$(this).attr('src')` there is no attribute called src in btn-1 anyways..whydon't you use class then

Comment: it worked on a simple demo i made. but now i'm trying to integrate it into my code. the html above is my code i'm working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes to your example but not quite sure what kinda effect are you expecting.  Hope this helps you. click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MhQpH/3/)

```
$('#btn-1').click(function() {
    $('#transferEffect').remove(); // Remove any existing one
    $('<style id="transferEffect" type="text/css">' + // Add new one
        '.ui-effects-transfer { background-image: url(' + $(".listing-image img").attr('src') + '); }' +
        '</style>').appendTo('head');
    $(".listing-image img").effect('transfer', {to: $('.listing-image')}, 1000);
});
```

**Edited :**

I have made a few more changes. here is the updated [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MhQpH/10/).

Comment: sorry forgot to add the css. trying to make the lego image move to <div class="transfer"> here is the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/MhQpH/5/

Comment: i'm trying to make the "save" button dynamic, so it will get the img src from closest <img> i used this but don't work var img = $(this).closest('.listing-image img').attr('src');  latest code is here http://jsfiddle.net/MhQpH/18/

Comment: works on the 1st img but not the second. this can't seem to find the 2nd img. var img = $(this).closest('.listing-image').find("img").attr("src");

Comment: ok, 1 final issue. when the "save" is clicked, only 1 image should move. closest() seems to move both images when the top "save" is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you can try traversing from div tag(class **pull-right)**.like this

`var desId = $('div.pull-right  > a ') .attr('id');`

if i`m not wrong i guess u can use this desId to call the click event.